# Pause controller action in Open vSwitch

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I am trying to instruct the switch to pause as described in http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt.

It is said that the action should be `controller(key=value)`, I assume that `pause` is the key and `True` is the value. I tried issuing, for example, the following command: (switch name c2)

```
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow c2 dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01,actions=controller:pause=True
```

but it does not work, writing that `pause` is unrecognized key.

Comment: What version of Open vSwitch are you using (`ovs-ofctl --version`)?

Comment: ovs-ofctl (Open vSwitch) 2.5.4
OpenFlow versions 0x1:0x4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like support for the pause controller action was [added in the **version 2.6.0**](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/commit/77ab5fd2a95ba2fef5bbe25aaa429776b9e29ea3) of Open vSwitch. Otherwise, the following syntax should work:

```
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow c2 "dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01,actions=controller(pause)"
```

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem. I upgraded OVS and this worked. Do you know how can I send such command with POX?

Comment: Glad I could help! No idea for POX, I've never used it.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use controllers very often.